Confusion about why time coordinate of Lorentz transformation and time dialation don't align?
If there is a stationary observer and one is moving to the right at 1/2 speed of light. And there is a light moving to the right at the speed of light. I tried to calculate the coordinates of light after one-second passes for the stationary observer from the perspective of the moving observer. Using Lorentz Transformation I get coordinates of light to be ((1/root(3))c, 1/root(3)). And then then I tried to calculate coordinates but for a light moving to the left instead. Using Lorentz Transformation I get coordinates of light to be ((-root(3))c, root(3)). Then I realized something that after 1 second passed for the stationary observer how can it be that both 1/root(3) seconds passed for the moving observer and root(3)seconds passed for the moving observer? Then I used time dilation formula to work out the time passing for the moving observer. The time calculated was root(3)/2 seconds for the moving observer when 1 second passes for the stationary observer. So my question is how is it that Lorentz transformation doesn't give the correct time value even though I applied it using the 1-second passing for the stationary observer? And how does it give different values for different time values for different lights? Which is the correct time passing for the moving observer when 1 second passes for the stationary observer?

OP has an earlier similar question: I am confused about this contradiction in special relativity?.
